# Where is Request type drop down in GeoServer authentication settings page?

Tags: geoserver, authentication

I am reading the [GeoServer tutorial about configuring digest authentication](http://docs.geoserver.org/2.8.3/user/security/tutorials/digest/index.html). The tutorial says that on the authentication page, the `Filter chains` panel, there is a `Request type` drop down, which I cannot find anywhere in my geoserver instance (2.8.3 from OSGeoLive 10).

According to documentation, the Filters Chain panel should look like this:
[image]

But mine looks differently like this:
[image]

Am I looking at the wrong panel, is the OSGeo version GeoServer different, or did something else go wrong?

By the way, the address on the browser is: `http://localhost/geoserver/web/?wicket:interface=:24:1:::`

Comment: Perhaps the user interface has changed and the tutorial in not up to date.